# GetProcessesByName() Throws Process performance counter is disabled

Tags: .net-1.1, performancecounter

We had an application that uses `Process.GetProcessesByName()` but it is failing only on one user PC with the following error:

> Process performance counter is disabled

I searched the registry for the **Disable Performance Counters** entry but it was not present with the value set to 1.

The user env is XP with administrative rights.

I know that on Windows Server 2003, the user account needs to be a member of the Performance Counter Users Group in order to accomplish this.

Any ideas on how to enable Process performance counter?

Answer (score -1):

Issues that can be responsible: .NET version isn't compatible , Performance Counters need to be enabled or permission problems

Quoted from [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/482b5994-32a4-4c95-a73f-3c05ca2aaf93/systeminvalidoperationexception-process-performance-counter-is-disabled-so-the-requested?forum=netfxbcl)

> In .NET 1.0/1.1, the Process class relys on performance counters to provide performance information regarding local and remote processes.
>
> .NET 2.0, this dependancy for local processes is no longer present.
>
> This exception can be thrown for a couple of reasons:
>
> 1. Performance counters are disabled - The Windows Resource Kit contains a tool called the Extensible Counter List that can be used to enable/disable counters
> 2. The user doesn't have enough rights - non-admin users (I think) may not have enough permissions to access the performance counters.

If it's possible, install .NET > 2.0 and target the newer version

There is a tutorial which shows you how to use the Extensible Counter List to enable Performance Counters [here](https://support.symantec.com/us/en/article.TECH40069.html)

> Open Performance Monitor by clicking Start > Run > Type in Perfmon and choose Ok.
>   Verify that the Process Monitor object exists, as illustrated in the screenshot posted above.
>
> If the Process object exists, choose all of the Process objects counters and all instances, click Add, and then watch the graph.
>
> Do they all run successfully?
>
> If the counters are missing, then you will need to enable them.
>   Microsoft provides several KB articles to handle this situation. Begin by reading http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?kbid=300956
>
> If the steps in this KB not work properly, and if your server is Microsoft Windows Server 2003, try the next step
>   Download and install the Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit on the Notification Server or Task Server
>
> Open the Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit command prompt
>   Type in "exctrlst.exe" to bring up the Extensible Counter List as shown in the screenshot below and scroll down and enable performance counters